# Unicode / Umlauts in urllib.request XML parsing

Tags: python, unicode, urllib

I’m struggling with urllib.request and unicode. I have a script that gets a list of city names, builds geonames.org API-request URLs from them and parses the output XML Data to display geonames information exactly in the way I need it. The script works fine as long as the cities names don’t contain any non-ASCII character like ö in Köln (I have to use german city names).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

urllist = []
citylist = ['Hamburg', 'Bremen']

for city in citylist:
    requestURL = 'http://api.geonames.org/search?name=' + city + '&maxRows=1&lang=de&username=demo'
    urllist.append(requestURL)

for url in urllist:
    root = ET.parse(urllib.request.urlopen(url)).getroot()
    items = root.findall('geoname')
    for item in items:
        print(item.find('name').text + ', ' + item.find('countryName').text + ' [' + item.find('lat').text + ',' + item.find('lng').text + '] [id:' + item.find('geonameId').text + ']')
```

When I switch `Hamburg` with `Köln` the Script exits with the error message `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)`.

One other thing that does not work is city names with blanks in it like `Bad Godesberg`. Am I using the wrong method to request the XML or is it that I have to decode my city names before building the URL (which is nearly definitely the case for two-word cities as when I use `Bad%20Godesberg` it works)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `urlencode`, for instance

> Python » Documentation [21.8.4. URL Quoting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting)
>
> Here is an example session that uses the GET method to retrieve a URL containing parameters:
>     [urllib-examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib-examples)
>
> ```
>    >>> import urllib.request
>    >>> import urllib.parse
>    >>> params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
>    >>> url = "http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/query?%s" % params
>    >>> with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
>            print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this, I’m going to look into urlencode! In the meantime I tried to run my code in Juypter Notebooks and it magically works without any changes which I can’t explain but which is perfect for now.